# Solving simultaneous equations using Laplace transforms

Tags: laplace-transform

$\displaystyle \frac{dx}{dt}+y=\sin t$

$\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dt}+x=\cos t$, given $\displaystyle x(0)=2, y(0)=0$

My Attempt:

Taking Laplace transforms on both sides
$\displaystyle $
$\displaystyle [s\bar x-2]+\bar y=\frac{1}{s^2+1} $

$\displaystyle [s\bar y-0]+\bar x=\frac{s}{s^2+1} $

$\displaystyle \bar x=\begin{vmatrix}
2 &1 \\ 
\frac{s}{s^2+1} &s 
\end{vmatrix}\div \begin{vmatrix}
s &1 \\ 
1 &s 
\end{vmatrix}$
Taking inverse,
$\displaystyle x=2\cos t$ and $\displaystyle x=-\sin t$

The given answer is: $\displaystyle x=e^t+e^{-t}$ and $\displaystyle x=e^{-t}-e^t+\sin t$

I can't find where I am going wrong. Please help.

Comment: Shouldn't the upper left element of your determinant in the numerator of $\bar{x}$ be $2+\dfrac{1}{1+s^2}$?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my silly mistake .. They will be the end of me ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We get the following system:
$$
\left(
  \begin{array}{l l}
   s & 1\\
  1 & s
  \end{array} \right) \cdot
\left(
  \begin{array}{l}
   \bar X\\
   \bar Y
  \end{array} \right) = 
\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
   2 + \frac{1}{s^2 + 1}\\
  \frac{s}{s^2+1}
  \end{array} \right)
$$
Then you will have to multiply the left hand side with 
$$
\left(
  \begin{array}{l l}
   s & 1\\
  1 & s
  \end{array} \right)^{-1}
$$
from the left, then inverse transform the expression